# MiniZinc does not find a solution to the scheduling problem

Tags: minizinc

I have a problem finding a solution using MiniZinc.

The task:
It is necessary to make a schedule of shifts for employees.
In one day there are three shifts: day (D), evening (E) and night (N).
It is necessary to draw up an optimal schedule, if possible avoiding undesirable  situations:

- Avoid single shifts (one shift between two breaks)
- Avoid single breaks (shift, break, shift)
- Avoid double breaks (shift, break, break, shift)
- After a night shift should be a full day off (three breaks in a row)

To find a solution, I minimize the number of undesirable situations.
When I start the calculation, MiniZinc displays several intermediate variants, but does not find a final solution.

Is it possible to somehow optimize the calculations?

```
include "regular.mzn"; 
int: n = 21;   
int: m = 6;

set of int: D = 1..n;
set of int: E = 1..m;

% Number of employees per shift
                         %|Sun    |Mon    |Tue      |Wen      |Thur   |Fri     |Sat    |
array[D] of int: SHIFTS = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1];
                         /*2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
                           2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
                           2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2];*/

% The range of the number of shifts per employee for the period ([|from, to)                         
array[E, 1..2] of int: DC_SHIFTS = [|0, 10 %emp1
                                    |0, 10 %emp2
                                    |0, 10 %emp3
                                    |0, 10 %emp4
                                    |0, 10 %emp5
                                    |0, 10 %emp6
                                    |];

%-------------------------------------------------
% Variables
%-------------------------------------------------

array[E, D] of var 1..4: X;
% Counters of avoidable situations
var int: OS_PENALTY; % break, shift, break (single shift)
var int: NS_PENALTY; % night shift, not break, not break, not break (full day off after a night shift)
var int: DS_PENALTY; % shift, break, break, shift (two breaks between shifts)
var int: OO_PENALTY; % shift, break, shift (one break between shifts)

%-------------------------------------------------
% Constraints
%-------------------------------------------------

constraint
  forall(d in D)(
      sum(e in E)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 4)) = SHIFTS[d]
  );

constraint
  forall(e in E)(
      sum(d in D)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 4)) >= DC_SHIFTS[e, 1]
      /\
      sum(d in D)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 4)) < DC_SHIFTS[e, 2]
  );

constraint
  forall(d in D)(
      if d mod 3 = 1 then forall(e in E)(X[e, d] = 1 \/ X[e, d] = 4) else
      if d mod 3 = 2 then forall(e in E)(X[e, d] = 2 \/ X[e, d] = 4) else
      forall(e in E)(X[e, d] = 3 \/ X[e, d] = 4) endif endif
  );


NS_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in D where d < max(D) - 2)(bool2int(
    X[e, d] = 3 \/ (X[e,d+1] != 4 /\ X[e,d + 2] != 4 /\ X[e,d + 3] != 4)
));

DS_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in D where d < max(D) - 2)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 4 \/ X[e, d + 1] = 4 \/ X[e, d + 2] = 4 \/ X[e, d + 3] != 4));

OS_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in D where d < max(D) - 1)(bool2int(X[e, d] = 4 /\ X[e, d + 1] != 4 /\ X[e, d + 2] = 4));

OO_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in D where d < max(D) - 1)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 4 \/ X[e, d + 1] = 4 \/ X[e, d + 2] != 4));

%-------------------------------------------------
% Solve
%-------------------------------------------------

solve minimize OS_PENALTY + NS_PENALTY + DS_PENALTY + OO_PENALTY;

%-------------------------------------------------
% Output
%-------------------------------------------------

array[1..4] of string: rest_view = ["D", "E", "N", "-"];

output 
[ 
   rest_view[fix(X[e, d])] ++
   if d = n then "\n" else "" endif
   | e in E, d in D
];
```

Comment: If this is an option for you, in MiniZinc IDE switching solver to OSICBC finds the optimal solution within a second.

Comment: I have tried to tune the model by restricting the variable domains, by using `let` to avoid recalculation of sums, by leaving out `bool2int()` etc. All this made no difference. `Chuffed` and `Gecode` were not able to find solutions below a penalty sum of 217. `OSICBC` arrives at penalty sum 213 and does diagnose this as minimum in 873msec.

Comment: @m-dedlovsky It looks like some of the penalty expressions are calculated wrong. I believe the following would match your descriptions correctly:

`NS_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in D where d < max(D) - 2)(bool2int(
    X[e, d] = 3 /\ (X[e,d+1] != 4 \/ X[e,d + 2] != 4 \/ X[e,d + 3] != 4)
));`,  `DS_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in D where d < max(D) - 2)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 4 /\ X[e, d + 1] = 4 /\ X[e, d + 2] = 4 /\ X[e, d + 3] != 4));` and `OO_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in D where d < max(D) - 1)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 4 /\ X[e, d + 1] = 4 /\ X[e, d + 2] != 4));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following changes to your model:

Change the declaration of `X` to `array[E, D] of var 0..1: X;` where `0` means break and `1` shift. Whether it's a day, evening or night shift is handled in the output section, where the results are transformed to show the shift type like `if fix(X[e, d]) == 0 then "-" else rest_view[1 + (d-1) mod 3] endif`.

Rewrite the constraints using globals like:

```
import "globals.mzn"; 
constraint
  forall(d in D)(
      exactly(SHIFTS[d], col(X, d), 1)
      %sum(e in E)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 0)) = SHIFTS[d]
  );

constraint
  forall(e in E)(
      global_cardinality_low_up(row(X, e), [1], [DC_SHIFTS[e, 1]], [DC_SHIFTS[e, 2] - 1])
      %sum(d in D)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 0)) >= DC_SHIFTS[e, 1]
      %/\
      %sum(d in D)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 0)) < DC_SHIFTS[e, 2]
  );

%constraint
%  forall(d in D)(
%      if d mod 3 = 1 then forall(e in E)(X[e, d] = 1 \/ X[e, d] = 4) else
%      if d mod 3 = 2 then forall(e in E)(X[e, d] = 2 \/ X[e, d] = 4) else
%      forall(e in E)(X[e, d] = 3 \/ X[e, d] = 4) endif endif
%  );
```

Rewrite the penalties like:

```
NS_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in 1..n - 3 where d mod 3 = 0)(bool2int(
    X[e, d] = 1 /\ (sum(i in 1..3)(X[e,d+i]) > 0)
));

DS_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in 1..n - 3)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 0 /\ X[e, d + 1] = 0 /\ X[e, d + 2] = 0 /\ X[e, d + 3] != 0));

OS_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in 1..n - 2)(bool2int(X[e, d] = 0 /\ X[e, d + 1] != 0 /\ X[e, d + 2] = 0));

OO_PENALTY = sum(e in E, d in 1..n - 2)(bool2int(X[e, d] != 0 /\ X[e, d + 1] = 0 /\ X[e, d + 2] != 0));
```